# Can you run code before super/this constructor?

Tags: apex, inheritance

I had an interesting scenario recently and wasn't sure off the top of my head if my desired inheritance model was possible. This finding might not be the most interesting or novel to some, but it took me a bit of research and experimentation to confirm, so I thought I'd share it here.

---

**Can a `super` constructor consume attributes set by inheriting types?**

Effectively, the constraint would look something like below.

```
public abstract with sharing class SuperType
{
    public String someAttribute;
    public SuperType()
    {
        system.assertNotEquals(null, someAttribute);
    }
}

public with sharing class ChildType extends SuperType
{
    public ChildType()
    {
        someAttribute = 'populated';
        super();
    }
}
```

Unsurprisingly, setting the attribute this way gives the error:

> Call to 'super()' must be the first statement in a constructor method

So is it actually possible to have a child type set attributes consumed in the super constructor?

```
public with sharing class ChildType extends SuperType
{
    public ChildType()
    {
        someAttribute = 'populated';
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thankfully, when I double checked order of execution for [Using Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm), I found what I needed (emphasis mine):

> The instance initialization code in a class is executed each time an object is instantiated from that class. ***These code blocks run before the constructor.***

So the below pattern works beautifully. I one-lined the initialization block in my code but expanded it here to be more clear what I'm doing.

```
public with sharing class ChildType extends SuperType
{
    {
        someAttribute = 'populated';
    }
    public ChildType()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was half expecting Betteridge's Law of Headlines (if you ask a question in the headline, the answer is "no") to come into play. Nice that it didn't here.

Comment: I suppose the utility here (over just having or adding a SuperType constructor that takes argument(s)) is that you can declare hyper-local variables (only accessible in the initialization block) and contain multiple, independent statements to handle complex setup without adding boilerplate code in the SuperType.

Comment: Adding every little thing you need into the constructor signature can also scale poorly.

Comment: Who deleted the comment thread? There were valid points raised in the thread that should (IMHO) be associated with this answer: 1. It means the child class makes assumptions about the super class's construction and initialization of attributes that are not obvious in the super class context (which could have significant issues during future development and refactoring - even worse if in separate same-namespace packages). 2. It won't work for final attributes. 3. It is not following normal conventions (parameterized constructors) and therefore may well cause confusion for later maintainers.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work for you, today, but the answer should be caveated.

Comment: It seemed somewhat contentious. I didn't delete because I disagree with you (which I do), but rather because the tone was a bit aggressive. And I do want to reiterate that long parameter lists are an anti-pattern. Recommending that strategy as a catch all has down sides too.

Comment: You don't have to have long parameter lists, but instead either multiple constructors that target anticipated use cases or (if these are too nebulous) the concept of using a fluent interface, either as the object itself OR as its single parameters object.

Comment: None of those patterns work for my use case. I really think we need to agree to disagree.

Comment: +1 for reminding me about initialization code blocks which I never use - are their good use cases (besides, perhaps, the above)?

Comment: It's the only one I've found so far. Seems to be _the_ compelling reason you would put code there, is if you need it to facilitate constructor chaining.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for posting this solution, worked great for me. Exact scenario.